# Is there a disadvantage of having <img> tag with Base64 as format of image in HTML document in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, image, base64

I am having angular components which load multiple images on a page all ranging from 20kb to 3.5 MB. The images are retrieved in Base64 format and embedded in HTML. Is there a disadvantage of using such format compared to image url? Does it impact app performance?

For e.g.

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4 //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />`

Consider the string in the img src attribute to be 3.5 MB in size.

Comment: it would block your page from fully rendering...

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment, when you embed images as "data URLs" inline with the page markup, the process of loading your content is somewhat different from what happens with traditional images loaded through separate URLs. It's up to you which behavior makes sense for your needs.

With embedded data URLs, all of the image data is loaded as part of the HTTP response to get your page. Combined with the fact that base64 encoding makes your image data somewhat bigger, that means that your page load time will be greater.

With traditional image URLs, the main page is smaller but each image has to be fetched with a separate HTTP request. Browsers are pretty good at that, but it means that your page may appear briefly *without* the images while those additional HTTP requests complete.

One person's advantage is another person's disadvantage, so again it's up to you. You could try both and see which you prefer.